# Defining a Record object with a single known key and its value

Tags: typescript

Apologies, this is kind of complicated, and I've been unable to create a simpler reproduction than what I've got here.  Feel free to edit the question title with something a bit more specific or descriptive.

I want to define a base data type of the shape:

```js
type AbstractBaseTypes = {
    [key: string] : {
        inputTypes: Record<string, unknown>; 
        outputType: unknown; 
    }
}
```

That is, there is a list of keys, each have corresponding record of input data, as well as a corresponding output datatype.

As an example, one would then create a 'concrete' version of this data type, like such:

```js
type KnownBaseTypes = {

    "text": {
         inputTypes: {
            label: string; 
            maxLength: number; 
        }
        outputType: string; 
    }, 
    "number": {
        inputTypes: {
            label: string; 
            min: number; 
            max: number;
            
        }, 
        outputType: number; 
    } 
}
```

The ultimate goal I'm going for is I want to create map, that for each of those keys, we create a function that takes three parameters:

- control object = a piece of data describing the key we are talking about, and the input data as described in that KnownBaseTypes.
- data - An 'partially known' record. ie. we know one key of it (from the control object) and its value type (based on the KnownBaseTypes outputType),
- callback - accepts the value of the output type.

ie. Here's how I would do this in plain javascript.

```js
const myDataManipulationMap = {

    "text": (data, controlObject, callback) => {

        const {
            key, inputData
        } = controlObject; 

        const {
            label, maxLength 
        } = inputData


        const newString = (label + data[key]).substr(0, maxLength); 

        const newData = {
            ...data, 
            [controlObject.key]: newString
        }; 

        callback(newData); 
    }, 

    "number": (data, controlObject, callback) => {

        const {
            key, inputData
        } = controlObject; 

        const {
            min, max, label 
        } = inputData


        const newNumber = min + Math.random() * (max - min); 

        const newData = {
            ...data, 
            [controlObject.key]: newString
        }; 

        callback(newData); 
    }
}
```

My approach for doing typings on this goes like this:

My control object:

```js
type ControlObject<T extends AbstractBaseTypes, K extends keyof T> = {
    key: string; 
    inputData: T[K]["inputTypes"];
};
```

And my partially known data references the key of the control object:

```js
type PartiallyKnownDataObject<T extends AbstractBaseTypes, K extends keyof T >  = {
    [ key in ControlObject<T, K>["key"] ] : T[K]["outputType"]
}
```

Putting it all together:

```js
type DataGenerationMap<T extends AbstractBaseTypes> = {
    [K in keyof T]: (
        data: PartiallyKnownDataObject<T,K>,
        controlObject: ControlObject<T,K>,
        callback: (data: PartiallyKnownDataObject<T,K>) => void
    ) => void; 
}
```

This *almost* does what I want.

The problem is, inside my functions 'partially known data' is asserted to have any number of keys, all with the `outputType` data type.

Whereas, I want to be able to only make assumptions about the type of the data accessible by `controlObject.key`. Attempts to access other keys should reveal an unknown data type.

```js
const myMap : DataGenerationMap<KnownBaseTypes> = {
    "text": (data, controlObject, callback) => {

        //snip
    }, 

    "number": (data, controlObject, callback) => {

        const {
            key, inputData
        } = controlObject; 

        const {
            min, max 
        } = inputData


        const a : string = min; // expected error 

        const b: number = data.foo;  //<-- should error

        callback(); //expected error 
        console.log(controlObject.inputData.foo); //expected error;  

        const newNumber = min + Math.random() * (max - min); 

        const newData = {
            ...data, 
            [controlObject.key]: newNumber
        }; 

        callback(newData); 
    }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggRgZ2AJwIYGNgCFUIgFXAgSgF4oBvAKClqgG0BrCEALiiWQEsA7AcwC6UdtTpiovMAFdghSAnYAlCOgD2yACYAeTrz4AaKFJ6MeqgO48AfAG4oNcbVUzpsou2OmLPOw9oBfKkCqKlBIKABpM0scPDliMkoQsQAiYAgAD2AUkT9HSRl4hSTHRwAbVDgIMvZdfl9S8QBbVAyAGQh+YAALdh4pJqrkBtLAxudgV3jalD0RgMM8lP7BiGQcktKCt3lcxrEm3j6Bofn9lozj1eH7Rv9F8ZdC9ygV09u6f3tgsOgAYVUPBQqjKAHk4AArFTALT4KCZdI8DQkeCcDDYXAEIgIQwReFZTrIqDMECqABmUHwVkSojoJJm3HqH1o2wAIqhgKh2Ph6BEBPQUtsiikBDYgr5QkQoAAFVDIYBcVBlMogKLedmc8FQzCw-GIomolDo2JY+S4vWEkgk8mUqDUml5ejElgSHhQAFA5AgrXQ2G4qwCkkiqBCbm8-kpCZTIgioIhX5QDWoADinTWHK4gIAsqgwLqEZbYIgjZgTUVqeRabRea7naSKfgBOwABR5MQaDlcmVyhVKlVqyxJn06-D6CJWfRtuhqT3eyHQ9ge4Fg+cjscTqe0DSqADKqiaEB6egA6lwehoky2O5z2LL5Yrlarojwh6uYaPxwBKMjUgBuqi4DQ8m-Ug-wAjRfGCEIZyQKAmhAHMwGERNO1THh0wVbNcy0AceDLbEK02Wg0gRDZm2vVBDBnZdh2AKi+zgDBGBA6lqE3KAYOAIj9hJQw2U7divnIaivRXbVgAlRpOO4xoKiqMpDAuDoum6ZlxCE11XCTEJ2Ok9DzB3WZ+ESZs5OqKAAGooAopgWAET8ADoECkYtkGbAAGRTWmUvgek-STSj0iBzCTB19joBzIooh5woYES53EhySSbV5gsMxk+EEgLHHQBimObfSk38tT7nsJY3jWMjoo4wEaLfejlUY9BmJ-JJdMBWCqx4lg+J4LSBLuRJ4rE6FsvEaSusaQ4eC8jI1LEDT+M5HSpI6rjUGQuo+ESaa7AAej2-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-DQVmKQEJLGskoQATjJDAUErIa7GKzFwVk69QBwBYTPdeudc4gCaBkHcF4QAwAEeMneXBkxZjAE0JBNi+DrwhKPK+hD15YD+H8Mx7lUBZl-jADZrIuDuUULPaUWBu7SivowDITRuhZjKN0HgMBFBNB3KgCIfCa632lMPSurJGDSmTE0HgfwGEQh3ggaU3QNBEKaH8NhbzGBlBYUgjIWBK5-FzqoNpBTFC527gAdlzpXFh5ir5lGcseGAs9b6YKwFwHeyYiHuR4IXXOWBOGMBETpEIQA)

What's going on here?

Comment: Where do you have unexpected error? Which part of code should be fixed?

Comment: @captain-yossarian I've pointed that out with `<-- should error`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

```js
type AbstractBaseTypes = {
    [key: string]: {
        inputTypes: Record<string, unknown>;
        outputType: unknown;
    }
}


type KnownBaseTypes = {
    "text": {
        inputTypes: {
            label: string;
            maxLength: number;
        }
        outputType: string;
    },
    "number": {
        inputTypes: {
            min: number;
            max: number;
        },
        outputType: number;
    }
}

type ControlObject<T extends AbstractBaseTypes, K extends keyof T> = {
    key: keyof KnownBaseTypes; // <-- you used `string` as a key type, that's why you ended up with {[index:string]:number} type
    inputData: T[K]["inputTypes"];
};

type PartiallyKnownDataObject<T extends AbstractBaseTypes, K extends keyof T> = {
    [key in ControlObject<T, K>["key"]]: T[K]["outputType"]
}

type DataGenerationMap<T extends AbstractBaseTypes> = {
    [K in keyof T]: (
        data: PartiallyKnownDataObject<T, K>,
        controlObject: ControlObject<T, K>,
        doSomethingWithdData: (data: PartiallyKnownDataObject<T, K>) => void
    ) => void;
}

type Result = PartiallyKnownDataObject<KnownBaseTypes, "number">


const myMap: DataGenerationMap<KnownBaseTypes> = {
    "text": (data, controlObject, callback) => {

        const {
            key, inputData
        } = controlObject;

        const {
            label, maxLength
        } = inputData


        const newString = (label + data[key]).substr(0, maxLength);

        const newData = {
            ...data,
            [controlObject.key]: newString
        };

        callback(newData);
    },

    "number": (data, controlObject, callback) => {

        const {
            key, inputData
        } = controlObject;

        const {
            min, max
        } = inputData


        const a: string = min; // expected error 

        console.log(data.foo); // <-- should error

        callback(); //expected error 
        console.log(controlObject.inputData.foo); //expected error;  

        const newNumber = min + Math.random() * (max - min);

        const newData = {
            ...data,
            [controlObject.key]: newNumber
        };

        callback(newData);
    }
}
```

Is it works for you?